# JS reusable block && DRY Saga

Tags: redux-saga

I've been using Catch block at the same page three times:

```
function* getSomeData() {
    try {
        // Catch block is used three times 
  } catch (error) {
    const failed = error && true;
    yield put({
      type: LOAD_DATA_ERROR,
      failed
    });
    yield call(delay, 2000);
    yield put({
      type: LOAD_DATA_ERROR,
      failed: false
    });
  }
}
```

I converted it in reusable piece of code. But I have a generator inside of generator.
Taking that in account, may I face unexpected behavior someday?

```
// Declaration
function* errorHandler(){
    yield put({
      type: LOAD_DATA_ERROR,
      failed: true
    });
    yield call(delay, 2000);
    yield put({
      type: LOAD_DATA_ERROR,
      failed: false
    });
  }

  // Place of use
  try{
    //-----------------
   } catch (err) {
    yield errorHandler();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your question and code in simple language if possible

Answer (score 1):

I think should be

```
yield * errorHandler();
```

It's basically like running the same code so you'll not have any problems. Here're some other suggestion:

- If you want to clear the error create a dedicated event like `CLEAR_DATA_ERROR`. It looks weird to use the same one for flushing the error out.
- `const failed = error && true;` looks kinda strange. If your idea is to get `failed` always truthy I can assure you that `error` is always there. You can't fall into a `catch` block without an error.

Comment: yes, you want to use yield* to delgate the call to errorHandler.  Otherwise, you can use the `call` effect to invoke errorHandler.